# Want idea JSON parsing using Scala

Tags: json, scala

Below is my JSON format:

```
{"copybook": {
    "item": {
        "storage-length": 1652,
        "item": [
            {
                "storage-length": 40,
                "level": "05",
                "name": "OBJECT-NAME",
                "display-length": 40,
                "position": 1,
                "picture": "X(40)"
            },
            {
                "storage-length": 8,
                "occurs-min": 0,
                "level": "05",
                "name": "C-TCRMANKEYBOBJ-OFFSET",
                "numeric": true,
                "display-length": 8,
                "position": 861,
                "occurs": 99,
                "depending-on": "C-TCRMANKEYBOBJ-COUNT",
                "picture": "9(8)"
            }
        ],
        "level": "01",
        "name": "TCRMCONTRACTBOBJ",
        "display-length": 1652,
        "position": 1
    },
    "filename": "test.cbl"
}}
```

How can I parse this json and convert it to CSV format? I am using Scala default JSON parser. The main problem I am facing is that I can not use case class to extract the data as all the item names are not same in item array.

This format is ok for me, please follow this link and paste the JSON - https://konklone.io/json/. Any scala code is appreciated. I am getting the below data:

```
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
val json2 = parse(jsonString, false) \\ "item"
val list = json2.values.asInstanceOf[List[Map[String, String]]]
    for (obj <- list) {
      //println(obj.keys) 
      //obj.values
      println (obj.toList.mkString(","))

    } 

(name,OBJECT-NAME),(storage-length,40),(picture,X(40)),(position,1),(display-length,40),(level,05) 
(name,C-TCRMANKEYBOBJ-OFFSET),(storage-length,8),(occurs-min,0),(occurs,99),(picture,9(8)),(position,861),(numeric,true),(depending-on,C-TCRMANKEYBOBJ-COUNT),(display-length,8),(level,05)
```

Comment: csv format DOES need fixed schema, and so you need to know all possible "flattened" paths in your json : like "copybook.item.storage-length", "copybook.item.item.storage-length" and all other "leaves" that you will get when you traverse down the road

Comment: Idea is to traverse the json and collect all the unique leaves. They will represent the csv full schema. In case with array items it's up to your design, but the most straightforward unwrap - this may be expanded to ${array_size} records where set of fields flattened [from each array item] are changing between the exploded records, and the rest of the json record (plain fields) are the same

Comment: This format is ok for me, please follow this link and paste the JSON - https://konklone.io/json/. Any scala code is appreciated. I am getting the below data:

Comment: Please email me for that

Answer (score 0):

https://circe.github.io/circe/ can work better for you in terms of traversing. Just try and read.